# Cannot install any new libraries in Eclipse (Luna) Maven

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

This error just started appearing, with any new maven dependencies I install. The dependency shows up in the Maven dependencies tree empty, and the project reports, for example:

`Description Resource Path Location Type Archive for required library: '~/.m2/repository/com/ning/async-http-client/1.8.14/async-http-client-1.8.14.jar' in project 'LB' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file  LB Build path Build Path Problem`

I viewed the POM file for each new dependency, and they all have this in them:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
This repo has moved to repo.boundlessgeo.com. Please update your settings.
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

So i discovered that the OpenGeo Maven Repo has moved, based on this:

```
<!-- <repository>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
    <id>opengeo</id>
    <name>OpenGeo Maven Repo</name>
    <url>http://repo.opengeo.org</url>
</repository> -->
```

Replaced with this:

```
<repository>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
    <id>boundless</id>
    <name>Boundless Maven Repository</name>
    <url>http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main</url>
</repository>
```

Even though I fixed this issue, all other dependencies still fail to install. Any idea why the POM files for any other repo keep getting the HTML notice from OpenGeo? How can I fix?

---

Here's the entire repo section of my pom.xml

```
<repositories>
<repository>
    <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
    <name>Java.net repo</name>
    <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
</repository>
<repository>
    <id>osgeo</id>
    <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repo</name>
    <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
</repository>
<repository>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
    <id>opengeo</id>
    <name>OpenGeo Maven Repo</name>
    <url>http://repo.opengeo.org</url>
</repository>
<repository>
    <id>central</id>
    <name>The Central Repository</name>
    <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
</repository>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Updated answer:

If you have a repository defined in your pom.xml which provides static content instead of a proper Maven repository (in this case http://repo.opengeo.org, which has moved to http://repo.boundlessgeo.org), Maven will download the static content as the pom, jar, etc and complain about it being corrupted later. **These invalid files will remain in your local repository until you delete them, even after you fix the problem repository**.

The simplest way to get rid of the invalid files would be to delete your entire ~/.m2/repository and download all artifacts fresh. However, you can also just delete the problem files (adjust the grepped message according to the static content in your invalid files):

```
grep -lrIZ "This repo has moved to repo.boundlessgeo.com" ~/.m2/repository \
  | xargs -r0 rm
```

Then do a normal `mvn clean install` and valid artifacts should be downloaded from the corrected repository.

See the original question for details on updating http://repo.opengeo.org to http://repo.boundlessgeo.org.

Note: Maven is likely downloading the invalid static content because repo.opengeo.org is returning a status code of 200.

---

#### Original answer:

Is it possible that you've somehow configured the old OpenGeo Maven Repo to be a mirror for all respositories? Maybe in your local settings.xml, or in a Nexus artifact repository?

I ran into something similar, where our Nexus server somehow had a bunch of non-OpenGeo artifacts in our proxied OpenGeo repository. Once the OpenGeo/BoundlessGeo repo moved, I got the "This repo has moved" message until I deleted the non-OpenGeo artifacts from the proxy repository.

Comment: settings.xml? Do you mean pom.xml? If not where is this settings.xml file stored?

Comment: Removed the references to the repos and their respective dependencies in my `pom.xml`, and that seems to have gotten rid of the blockage. It's too bad because I need some of those libs. =/

Comment: settings.xml is usually in ~/.m2, but if you haven't touched it that's likely not your problem. If removing the repos from your pom.xml fixed it, the problem is probably that one of those repos has a configuration problem. Can you post your `repositories` section? You could try removing them one at a time to see which one has the problem. Hopefully the dependencies in the problem repo are available elsewhere.

Comment: Didn't you already fix the boundless repo definition (change from opengeo)? Also, you don't need to declare central in your repositories, it gets used by default. Once you fix boundless and remove central, try a `mvn clean install` again. If that doesn't work your local repository may have some problem. You can delete the repository and redownload all artifacts (delete ~/.m2/repository) or test using a temporary/alternate local repository location (`mvn clean install mvn package -Dmaven.repo.local=/tmp/test_mvn_repo`).

Comment: Oh yeah I had to pull an old copy of my POM from Git, so that's why boundless didn't show up. Yes it's fixed though. I'll remove central as well, as I didn't know that it was a default repo. Good to know. Thanks.